# `FindMinimum` with compiled function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, compile

I don't know how to fix this problem:

```
In[175]:= test = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, If[Sin[x] > 0.1, Tan[x], 0]];
FindMinimum[test[x], {x, 1.}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

During evaluation of In[175]:= CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>

Out[176]= {0., {x -> -1.02705}}
```

I understand why it's complaining. But I need to use compile as my function has many lines with all sorts of comditionals. Speed is important. Stuck with this optimization step of `FindMinimum`. Any idea how to fix it without derailing up `Compile`?

Comment: Indeed a duplicate. But there is a different problem too with your compiled function: it is not *really* compiled.  That's because the "else" branch of the `If` is missing, which is forcing Mathematica to resort to non-compiled evaluation to handle it.  To understand why, consider what would happen if `Sin[x] < 0.1`.  Search this site for `CompilePrint` to see how to diagnose the problem.  Use something like `If[Sin[x] > 0.1, Tan[x], 0]` to fix it.

Comment: But creating an additional function is the only way? Isn't it going to slow down everything?

Comment: You should test, but I don't think so.  That additional layer should add very little overhead.  If that overhead does really make a significant difference, relative to the execution time of the compiled function, then it is quite possible that compilation didn't help anyway ... In this case compilation is most helpful if `test` takes a non-trivial amount of time uncompiled.  But actually: you don't *need* to create an additional function. You can just ignore the error. It won't affect the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest altering the definition of `test` as follows:

```
test = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
  If[Sin[x] > 0.1, Tan[x], 0.], 
  "RuntimeOptions" -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False
 ];
```

Note that the `0` third argument of `If` is changed to `0.`. While it seems to compile correctly anyway for this particular example, my experience has been that `Compile` can sometimes fail to correctly cast types, and this may be the case in your larger function. So, I personally prefer to make these explicit, i.e. not to write an integer where a real-typed register is going to hold the result. To expand on [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98449/findminimum-with-compiled-function#comment266989_98449), if nothing is given as the third argument then it is an implicit `Null`. This is of type `Void`, which cannot be cast to a real, and so will guarantee a failure to compile.

The [other option](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuntimeOptions.html) performs as a close functional analog of a `_?NumericQ` pattern test in the definition, as it is shown in the linked question.